# Compilation error in main method

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax-error, subclass

```
package morepackage;

public class Subclass extends Superclass {
    public static void main ( String args[] )
    {
        String name = super.text;//compilation error in this line
        String name1 = text;//no compilation error in this line
    }
}
```

The code of the superclass is:

```
public class Superclass
{
    static String text = "flowers";
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why the line String name = super.text is showing error

while the line String name1 = text; is not showing error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing `super`, which pertains to an instance of `SubClass`, in a `static` context, which cannot know about instances - i.e. your `static void main` method pertains to the `class SubClass`, not to any of its instances.

Since `text` is `static` in `SuperClass`, you can reference `SuperClass.text` instead, provided you have the right access (here, within the same package).

Answer (score 3):

Because you have declared it as static in the superclass it is a class variable and should be accessed as `Superclass.text`.